# AWS Cognito - Federated Identities - identiy and sync error - IOS - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am a new developer and I am creating a new app which uses AWS for lots of the backend, and is iOS in swift for the front end. 
Initially I am trying to get the login in process working using federated identities with Facebook, Google and Twitter. I also want to use a cognito user pool, but would like to get the social media logins going first. I have set up the code for the social networks and they are bringing in the info to the app, however I am struggling to get the data to sync up to cognito as authenticated users so that once logged in the users can access data from Dynamo DB and other AWS services.

My App Delegate is

import UIKit
import CoreData
import TwitterKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import GoogleSignIn
import Google
import AWSCognito
import AWSCore

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    Twitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:"############", consumerSecret:"#####################")

    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)


    return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let directedByFB =  FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)

    let directedByGGL = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    let directedByTWTR =  Twitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)

    return directedByGGL || directedByTWTR || directedByFB 
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    self.saveContext()
}

// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "vade_mecum_rock")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

}

My View Controller

import UIKit
import TwitterKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import Google
import GoogleSignIn
import AWSCognito
import AWSCore

class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate, AWSIdentityProviderManager{

```
var socialNetworkUsed = ""
var twitterIDToken = ""
var facebookIDToken = ""
var googleIDToken = ""
var twitterHasSegued = false //used to stop twitter interupting the segue into the app after login has happened

@IBAction func loginWIthEmailButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print("login With Email Pressed")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "emailLogin", sender: self)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loginWithTwitter()
    loginWithFacebook()
    loginWithGoogle()
    //getCognitoID()

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "#################"

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().shouldFetchBasicProfile = true

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func loginWithTwitter () {

    let logInButton = TWTRLogInButton { (session, error) in
        if let unwrappedSession = session {

            self.socialNetworkUsed = "Twitter"
            self.twitterIDToken = unwrappedSession.authToken + ";" + unwrappedSession.authTokenSecret


            let client = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser()

            client.requestEmail { email, error in
                if (email != nil) {
                    print("signed in as \(String(describing: session?.userName))")
                    print(email!)


                } else {
                    print("error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                }
            }

            self.signInToCognito(theUser: unwrappedSession)
            self.twitterHasSegued = true

        } else {
            NSLog("Login error: %@", error!.localizedDescription);
        }

    }

    if twitterHasSegued == false {
    // TODO: Change where the log in button is positioned in your view
    let button = logInButton
    button.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(button)
    }
}

func loginWithFacebook () {

    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
    loginButton.center.y = self.view.center.y/3
    loginButton.center.x = self.view.center.x

    self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
    loginButton.delegate = self

}



public func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if result != nil {
    self.socialNetworkUsed = "Facebook"
    if let theUser = result {
        self.facebookIDToken = theUser.token.tokenString
        print("First token \(facebookIDToken)")
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"me", parameters: ["fields" : "id, name, email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
            if error == nil {
                self.facebookIDToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString

                print("Second token \(self.facebookIDToken)")


                let data:[String:AnyObject] = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                print("Facebook logged in: \(data["name"]!)\(data["email"]!)")

                self.signInToCognito(theUser: data)

            } else {
                print("Error Getting Info \(error!)");
            }
        })
        }}
}


/**
 Sent to the delegate when the button was used to logout.
 - Parameter loginButton: The button that was clicked.
 */
public func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!){
    print("loggedout of facebook")
}

func loginWithGoogle () {
    let loginButton = GIDSignInButton()
    loginButton.center.y = view.center.y/1.5
    loginButton.center.x = view.center.x

    view.addSubview(loginButton)


}
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if (error == nil) {
        socialNetworkUsed = "Google"
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
        self.googleIDToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
        let fullName = user.profile.name
        let givenName = user.profile.givenName
        let familyName = user.profile.familyName
        let email = user.profile.email
        signInToCognito(theUser: user)
        print(userId, fullName, email, givenName, familyName)

        // ...
    } else {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

func signInToCognito (theUser: Any) {

    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:.EUWest2, identityPoolId:"#######################",identityProviderManager: self)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.EUWest2, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)

    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration



    credentialsProvider.getIdentityId().continueWith { (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in

        if (task.error != nil) {
            print("Error: " + (task.error?.localizedDescription)!)

        } else {
            // the task result will contain the identity id
            let cognitoId = task.result
            let syncClient = AWSCognito.default()
            print("sync client is \(syncClient.configuration.userAgent)")
        }
        return nil
    }


        let syncClient = AWSCognito.default()
        // Create a record in a dataset and synchronize with the server
        let dataset = syncClient.openOrCreateDataset("myDataset")

        if self.socialNetworkUsed == "Twitter" { // if they have used twitter to login
            let user = theUser as! TWTRSession
            dataset.setString(user.userName, forKey:"userName")
            dataset.setString("Mystery Climber", forKey: "name")
            let client = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser()

            client.requestEmail { email, error in
                if (email != nil) {
                    dataset.setString(email, forKey: "email")
                    print(email)
                } else {
                    print("error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                    dataset.setString("none@none.com", forKey: "email")
                }
            }

        } else if self.socialNetworkUsed == "Facebook" { // if they have used facebook to login
            let user = theUser as! [String : AnyObject]
            print("sign in to cognotio function facebook section \(user["name"]) & \(user["email"])")
            dataset.setString(user["name"] as! String, forKey: "name")
            if let email = user["email"] as? String {
                dataset.setString(email, forKey: "email")
            }

        } else if self.socialNetworkUsed == "Google" {//if they have used google to login
            let user = theUser as! GIDGoogleUser
            dataset.setString(user.profile.email, forKey: "email")
            dataset.setString(user.profile.name, forKey: "name")
        }

        dataset.synchronize().continueWith {(task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
            if task.error != nil {
                print("dataset error\(task.error)")
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTheHomePage", sender: self)
                }
            }
            return () as AnyObject
        }


    print(self.socialNetworkUsed)

}


public func logins() -> AWSTask<NSDictionary> {
    if socialNetworkUsed == "Twitter" {
        let result = NSDictionary(dictionary: [AWSIdentityProviderTwitter: twitterIDToken])
        print("Twitter results done")
        return AWSTask(result: result)
    } else if socialNetworkUsed == "Facebook" {
        if let token = FBSDKAccessToken.current() {
            print("Facebook results done")
            return AWSTask(result: [AWSIdentityProviderFacebook: token])
        } else {
            return AWSTask(error:NSError(domain: "Facebook Login", code: -1 , userInfo: ["Facebook" : "No current Facebook access token"]))}
    }else if socialNetworkUsed == "Google" {
        let result = NSDictionary(dictionary: [AWSIdentityProviderGoogle: googleIDToken])
        print("Google results done \(result.allValues)")
        return AWSTask(result: result)

    } else {
        let result = NSDictionary(dictionary: [AWSIdentityProvider.self: facebookIDToken])
        return AWSTask(result: result)
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated I have tried to find the answer but all the amazon docs seem out of date.

When I run the app I get the following errors.

dataset errorOptional(Error Domain=com.amazon.cognito.AWSCognitoErrorDomain Code=-4000 "(null)")
Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain error 8.)

Comment: Hi am also getting this same error l(Error Domain=com.amazon.cognito.AWSCognitoErrorDomain Code=-4000 "(null)").  Did u solve this. This happens for me if I sync my gplus credentials in AWSCognitoDataset.

Comment: I solved it in the end by switching to google cloud using Firebase I could create the same functionality, in half the time with many less errors. I know that's probably not that helpful if you are already a long way down the road with AWS.